# Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor queue cleared when server goes down?pp

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool

Regarding the behavior of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor:
Say I set the queue size to 500. Maxpoolsize is 100. If there were 500 requests that came in, does the pool contains 100 and the queue contains 400? Meaning additional 100 request can be added at that time? 
If there are requests currently in queue and the server goes down, are the requests gone? Will the executor handle the cleaning up of currently running threads?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tasks taken off the queue will not count towards the queue size, so you could add that 100 requests.

As for when the server goes down, this depends on why it went down. If the process was abruptly killed (like with a SIGKILL), no clean up will be done. Otherwise it depends on how the task is implemented. `ThreadPoolExecutor` itself doesn't do anything that requires a "clean up". If the task was doing something that requires a clean up, then the task needs to take care of that. In particular, the task thread will get interrupted when the server goes down and it should do whatever clean up that is necessary upon that.